# $X$ be a set and $d_1$, $d_2$ two metrics on $X$. Prove that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are topologically equivalent if and only if identity is a homemorphism.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a set and $d_1$, $d_2$ two metrics on $X$. Prove that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are topologically equivalent if and only if identity is a homemorphism. ( $id(x)=x, \ \forall x\in X$)
I am self study metric space theory and I come up with this problen. I know when $d_1$, and $d_2$ are topological equivalent, but I don't know to to connect this information with homemophism.

Comment: What is your definition of equivalent metrics?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy for all x,y $\alpha\cdot d_1(x,y)\leq d_2(x,y)\leq \beta d_1(x,y)$

Comment: The resuls is not true. If $d_1$ is the usual metric on $\mathbb R$ and $d_2(x,y)=\frac {|x-y|} {1+|x-y|}$ then the  identity map is a homeomorhism but there is no constant $c$ such that $d_1(x,y) \leq cd_2(x,y)$.

Comment: @josf: That is not the definition of **topologically** equivalent metrics: it’s the definition of [**strongly** equivalent metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics). The theorem is true for topologically equivalent metrics, but not for strongly equivalent metrics.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you my mistake

Comment: @josf: You’re welcome. Let $X_1$ denote $X$ with the topology generated by $d_1$ and $X_2$ denote $X$ with the topology generated by $d_2$. Show that if the identity map from $X_1$ to $X_2$ is a homeomorphism, then $X_1$ and $X_2$ have exactly the same open sets and therefore the same topologies.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott can you please give me more details beacuse I am beginer in this area.

Comment: @josf: I really can’t say much more than that without simply doing the problem for you, which I really don’t want to do. It is a genuinely trivial problem; if you’re having trouble, you may be making it harder than it really is.